# swap underscore 1.8.3 for lodash 4.2.1 in backbone marionette 2.4.4

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette, lodash

Is this even possible?  Keep reading conflicting reports on this.

I have a Marionette app, just upgraded to 2.4.4.

If I drop in lodash in place of underscore - using requireJS,

```
 map: {
  '*': {
    'underscore': 'lodash'
  }
},

//  'underscore':'/resource/vendor/backbone.marionette/underscore',
'lodash':'/resource/vendor/lodash/lodash.min',
```

I get the following error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vent' of undefined
```

lodash is loading up ok, just marionette is complaining.

It appears that the context `this` on line `466` is undefined

```
 463 _proxyMethods: function() {
 464     _.each([ "vent", "commands", "reqres" ], function(system) {
 465       _.each(messageSystems[system], function(method) {
 466         this[system][method] = proxyMethod(this, system, method);
 467       }, this);
 468     }, this);
 469   }
```

Any advice?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It is not the case that `messageSystems` is `undefined` so that line 465 (`messageSystems[system]`) is failing?

Comment: No, its odd.  Using the debugger, its def `this` that is undefined.   It is trying to resolve...  `this["vent"]["on"]`

Comment: I thought it might be something do with the nested each, both passing in `this` as the context - but I mocked up the same function above and it works fine

Comment: Hmm, lodash no longer has the `context` as the third param in `.each`...  ` function forEach(collection, iteratee) {
    return baseEach(collection, toFunction(iteratee));
  }`  So the context is lost in the above

Comment: Yeah, that is it, lodash 3.10.1 works fine - its the lack of context in the newer lodash that marionette is not compatible with

Comment: Nice find! Maybe you should add an answer? I bet more people would like to know :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone else looking at this, the answer is no.

Lodash `3.10.1` is fine, but the `4.x` release has removed the `context` option from many of the functions, which breaks `Marionette`.

The old way was

```
    _.each(collection, iteratee, context);
```

The new way is

```
_.each(collection, _.bind(iteratee, context));
```

But so far so good with using `3.10.1` with the above requireJS set up.

So until `Marionette` is updated, you have to hold off on `4.x`

Comment: Do you find a noticeable difference in speed since the switch? :)

Comment: @Tholle No, no noticeable difference in speed